# I have a weird syntax error: "operator expected"

Tags: syntax, ocaml

Syntax Error

```
type directive = TurnLeft | TurnRight | StepForward of int | StepBackward of int
type path = directive list
let sample_path = (StepForward 1 :: StepForward 2 :: TurnLeft:: StepBackward 3 :: TurnLeft :: StepForward 1 ::[])

let inverse directive = 
if directive =TurnLeft then TurnRight
else if directive = TurnRight then TurnLeft
  else if directive = (StepForward of int)  then (StepBackward of int) 
  else (StepForward of int)
;;
```

Can anyone see what the problem is here? The function is supposed to to invert each element of `directive`. Example: `TurnLeft` -> `TurnRight` and `StepForward 3` -> `StepForward 3`.

Comment: As you appear to quite new to OCaml, please have a read through the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ocaml/info). There are lots of good resources linked from there.

Answer (score 3):

The OCaml way to analyze the shape of data is to use pattern matching:

```
let inverse directive = match directive with
| TurnRight -> ...
| TurnLeft -> ...
| Stepforward n -> ...
| Stepbackward n -> ...
```

In particular:

- `x = y` is an equality test without a preceding let
- The form `Constructor of type_expression` can only be used when defining a variant type:

```
type t = A of int
```

and is not a syntactically valid expression (or pattern).